# Where has the Twig function 'render' in templates gone?

Tags: php, twig, silex

I have just updated my dependencies for my Silex application and now suddenly one of my templates is failing with the error:

```
Twig_Error_Syntax: The function "render" does not exist.
```

This was working fine before I performed a `composer update`.  From the composer output the following have been updated:

```
- Removing symfony/options-resolver (v2.6.7)
- Installing symfony/options-resolver (v2.7.0)
  Downloading: 100%

- Removing symfony/intl (v2.6.7)
- Installing symfony/intl (v2.7.0)
  Downloading: 100%

- Removing symfony/form (v2.6.7)
- Installing symfony/form (v2.7.0)
  Downloading: 100%

- Removing symfony/translation (v2.6.7)
- Installing symfony/translation (v2.7.0)
  Downloading: 100%

- Removing symfony/validator (v2.6.7)
- Installing symfony/validator (v2.7.0)
  Downloading: 100%

- Removing symfony/security (v2.6.7)
- Installing symfony/security (v2.7.0)
  Downloading: 100%

- Removing symfony/finder (v2.6.7)
- Installing symfony/finder (v2.7.0)
  Downloading: 100%

- Removing symfony/process (v2.6.7)
- Installing symfony/process (v2.7.0)
  Downloading: 100%

- Removing symfony/twig-bridge (v2.6.7)
- Installing symfony/twig-bridge (v2.7.0)
  Downloading: 100%

- Removing symfony/web-profiler-bundle (v2.6.7)
- Installing symfony/web-profiler-bundle (v2.7.0)
  Downloading: 100%

- Removing symfony/stopwatch (v2.6.7)
- Installing symfony/stopwatch (v2.7.0)
  Downloading: 100%
```

The code that was working within my template is:

```
{{ render (url('navigation')) | raw }}
```

I cannot find anything that suggests this function has been deprecated or what it has been replaced with.  I am not sure which of the updates has caused this problem, but i suspect it is Twig-Bridge.  I am using Twig version 1.18.1.

I am a bit stuck as to what the issue is here and it is causing me some problems so any help would be great.

I acknowlegde the fact that I should have pegged the version of the packages I am using so I can test upgrades in a more methodical manner.

Thanks, Russell

Update 1:

An update to provide some more context.

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "silex/silex": "~1.2",
    "silex/web-profiler": "1.0.*@dev",

    "ruflin/elastica": "1.3.*@dev",
    "dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider": "1.0.*@dev",

    "monolog/monolog": "1.9.1",

    "twig/twig": "1.18.*@dev",
    "twig/extensions": "1.2.*@dev",

    "symfony/yaml": "~2.4",
    "symfony/console": "~2.4",
    "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.4",
    "symfony/config": "~2.4",
    "symfony/monolog-bridge": "~2.4",
    "symfony/serializer": "~2.4",
    "symfony/form": "~2.4",
    "symfony/validator": "~2.4",
    "symfony/translation": "~2.4",
    "symfony/security": "~2.4",

    "macedigital/silex-jms-serializer": "1.0.0",
    "jdesrosiers/silex-jms-serializer-provider": "~0.1",

    "mheap/silex-gravatar": "dev-master",
    "mheap/gravatar-php": "dev-master",
    "mheap/silex-assetic": "1.0.4",

    "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",

    "predis/service-provider": "dev-master",

    "pear/archive_tar": "dev-master",
    "pear/pear_exception": "1.0.*@dev",
    "wapmorgan/unified-archive": "dev-master",

    "sybio/image-workshop": "dev-master",
    "sybio/gif-frame-extractor": "dev-master",
    "sybio/gif-creator": "dev-master",

    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php" : "*",

    "kilte/silex-pagination": "1.1.*@dev",

    "thispagecannotbefound/silex-markdown-parser": "dev-master",

    "erusev/parsedown": "~1.4",
    "erusev/parsedown-extra": "dev-master"
 }
```

I register the Twig and UrlGenerator services using the following:

```
$app->register ( new \Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider () );
$app -> register (new \Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
        'twig.options' => array("debug" => true)
    ));

$app['twig'] = $app -> share($app -> extend('twig', function($twig, $app) {
        $twig -> addExtension(new \Twig_Extension_Debug());
        return $twig;
    }));
```

Twig itself is still working and any template that does not have '{{ render }}' in it will work without issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. Did you register HttpFragmentServiceProvider before registering the Web Profiler? It is not obvious, but the documentation mentions about it [here](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-WebProfiler). It worked nicely for me.

Regards

Comment: awesome! same error and after adding `$app->register(new HttpFragmentServiceProvider());` error was gone!

Comment: Perfect, this was the fix.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:

- `twig/twig` (Maybe you have deleted it before performing composer update) and `symfony/twig-bridge` installed via composer.
  and
- Register `TwigServiceProvider()` and `UrlGeneratorServiceProvider()`

  ```
  $app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(  
    'twig.path' => \__DIR__.'/path/to/templates/',  
  ));

  $app->register(new UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I do still have ```twig/twig``` and ```symfony/twig-bridge``` in my composer.json file.  The two services are registered.  I will update my original question with these bits.